# Can we use dhtmlxscheduler in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use dhtmlxscheduler in asp.net.

But i do not know how to bind event data with it.

Even i do not know it works in asp.net or not.

Can any one help me for this?

Please help me guys.

Thanks,

Rajbir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dhtmlxScheduler.net works for asp.net, there is a sample project in the package(must be in package/Scheduler.ASP.NET).
also here is related blog post
http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/04/03/simple-event-calendar-asp-net.aspx